# How I can write the name of a file from a variable in Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to create a new file with the extension .bat using the value of a variable.

For example, I type "apple" and then the script should create a file called apple.bat.
I believe the script should be

```
set /p nume=Type the name | fsutil file createnew %nume%.bat 100
```

but the result is "%nume%.bat" and not "apple.bat"

Comment: Get rid of the `|` and put `fsutil file createnew %nume%.bat 100` on a separate line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@SomethingDark's comment contains the crucial pointer: the `fsutil` command must be on a *separate line* in order to access the newly assigned `%nume%` variable.

Apart from that, you should use `&` (unconditional) or `&&` (only if the command on the left succeeded) to chain commands; `|` (a pipe) only makes sense if you want output from the command on the left to serve as input to the command on the right. This does *not* apply here, as the `set` command doesn't produce output.

Therefore, use the following:

```
set /p name="Type a name: "
fsutil file createnew "%name%.bat" 100
```

<sup>Note how I've *double-quoted* the whole filename expression to ensure that it works correctly with names with embedded spaces.</sup>

The reason that these two commands must be on *separate* lines is that `cmd.exe`, the Windows command processor, expands all `%<name>%` variable references *before* a command is executed.
That is, `%name%` expands to whatever value variable `name` had *before* the value was prompted for with `set`; if that variable hasn't been set yet, *literal* `%name%` will print *at the command prompt*; by contrast, *in a batch file* the variable reference will expand to the *empty string*.

There is, however, a way to change this behavior: if you turn on *delayed expansion*, you can use
`!<name>!` variable references to have their values expanded *delayed*, i.e., to have their expansion happen *at the time of access*.

- Interactively, you can turn this feature on by starting a new `cmd.exe` instance with option `/V:ON`.

```
cmd.exe /V:ON  # start a new cmd.exe instance with delayed expansion enabled
set /p name="Type a name: " && fsutil file createnew "!name!.bat" 100
```

- In a batch file, use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`; note that `setlocal` creates a script-local scope for your variables, which, however, is generally desirable.

Comment: @SomethingDark: Thanks for the tip; I've updated the answer. Double-quoting strings / variable references that do / may  contain spaces is generally advisable. That said, whether you double-quote the prompt string for `set /p` or not has no impact on the value entered by the user and therefore no impact on the value stored.